# recuperar datos de formulario con spring?

Tags: java, spring, controller

tengo este metodo en el controller que me redirecciona a la pagina donde esta el formulario

```html
   @RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("consultaForm", new Consulta());
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

en el model addAtribute, le paso el objeto que quiero llenar con los datos del formulario, pero como jalo esos datos del objeto?, lo cambie de la siguiente manera

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Consulta consul, Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("consultaForm", consul);
        system.out.println("prueba" +consul.getClavePago()) 
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al llenar el formulario y dar click en el boton  buscar, yo obtener esos valores del formulario y verlos en consola
y puse un system a ver si pintaba un campo del fomulario, pero lo saca nullo, y es que cuando se inicia la pagina en automatico entra en ese metodo y  lo pone nullo, y ni siquiera le meti valor al input del formulario, como le puedo hacer para que no lo tome nullo luego luego que inicia la pagina, sino hasta que meta yo un valor y de click en buscar

este es mi firmulario

```html
<form: form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
  <tr>
    <td><label>CENTRO PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="pago" path="nombrePago"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>DIRECC PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="direccpago" path="direccPago"/></td>
    <input type="submit" />
   </tr>


</form>
```

lo que esta adentro de path, son los atributos que tengo en mi objeto
cuales la mejor manera de obtener esos datos?
vi que se podia con RequestParam, me parece pero no se como se usa
ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes añadir en el controlador un método que sepa gestionar el POST de ese formulario.

En el código HTML, define el action (la ruta a la que harás el envío de datos) por claridad:

```
<form:form id="consulta" action="/doconsulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
    <tr>
        <td><label>CENTRO PAGO</label></td>
        <td><form:input type="text" id="pago" path="nombrePago"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label>DIRECC PAGO</label></td>
        <td><form:input type="text" id="direccpago" path="direccPago"/></td>
        <input type="submit" />
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

Y en el controlador, añades el siguiente método:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doconsulta", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ejecutaConsulta(@ModelAttribute("consultaForm") Consulta consulta, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    //...
}
```

Eso suponiendo que esos input *pago* y *direccpago* que has definido en el formulario son atributos de la clase Consulta.

El primer método que habías definido, para el GET, ya está bien, no necesitas hacer lo que comentas luego.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, ya lo hice tal cual, solo que no hace nada cuando doy click en el botón, no entra al método y una pregunta, en este nuevo método lo que hago es volver a redireccionar la misma página que el  primer método, es correcto hacerlo?

Comment: ya me funciono, gracias!!

Comment: Perfecto! Pues si puedes marcarla como respuesta correcta sería de agradecer :)

Answer (score 0):

Debes de cambiar este pedazo:

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Consulta consul, Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("consultaForm", consul);
        system.out.println("prueba" +consul.getClavePago()) 
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

En automático te recogerá los name del form que coincidan con tu objeto `consul` de la clase `Consulta` (Nota que cambie de `GET` a `POST`). Puedes usar `serialize` con `load` de `JQuery` para hacer una envío post sin recargar la página.

El primer controlador está bien. Lo que hace es crear `new Consulta()` para pasarlo al formulario.

```html
   @RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("consultaForm", new Consulta());
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

Como dato principal